# couldn't get current server API group l failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, certificate

I'm creating a username named "client" in kubernetes for a developer. I'm running a local master node. I completed the following steps:

```
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj "/CN=client/0=dev
sudo openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA /root/.ke/ca.crt -CAKey /root/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 500
openssl x509 -in client.crt -noout -text
```

configure kubectl for user:

```bash
kubectl config -set-cluster master-node --server=https://192.168.0.93:8443 --certificate=authority=/ca.crt 
kubectl config set-credentials client --client-certification=client.crt --client=client.key
kubectl config set-context client --cluster=master --user=client
kubectl config use-context client
```

My config file is:
apiVersion: v1
clusters:

- cluster:
     certificate-authority-data: BASE64 CERT. I pasted ca.crt and tried client.crt as well.
     server: https://master-node:6443
  name: kubernetes
- cluster:
     certificate-authority: /home/hernan/RBAC/client.crt
     server: https://192.168.0.93:6443
  name: master

contexts:

- context:
     cluster: master
     user: client
  name: client
- context:
     cluster: master
     user: hernan
  name: hernan
- context:
     cluster: kubernetes
      user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes

current-context: client
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:

- name: client
  user:
     client-certificate: /home/hernan/RBAC/client.crt
     client-key: /home/hernan/RBAC/client.key

I'm running `kubectl --kubeconfig=/home/.kube/config.client get pods and I get`

```
E0620 11:31:07.299522   15030 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.0.93:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
unknown authority
```

Any ideas?

I tried using the ca.crt and client.crt in the certificate-authority-data encoded field. All the files have the correct permissions. I regenerated the files after checking with `openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in client.crt | openssl md5`.

Comment: yes that is a self signed certificate, so you get that error. In the case of browser, it will ask you whether should this be trusted or not, and you choose to `trust` it since it is your own cert so you click on proceed. Not sure whether you are getting options to proceed despite that message

Comment: my point is that yes that is expected behavior but you should be able to force it trust the connection since this is your own cert and that is also signed by you

Comment: HI JBone. Thanks for your quick reply. Do you know how do I force-trust the connection for kubectl, not a browser? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @herlit, unfortunately I dont know how to do that in kubectl. I will see if I can google around and come up with a suggestion

Comment: The first `openssl` command is off syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the correct certificate from `/etc/kubernetes/pki` to generate the client.crt file at the beginning of the process.

`sudo do openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA /root/.ke/ca.crt -CAKey /root/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 500`
replaced `/root/.ke/ca.crt` with `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt` and the same with the key.